# Element <Batch> of parameter updates is missing or invalid exception occurs while deleting sharepoint list record

Tags: sharepoint

I'm getting

> Element <batch>
>   of parameter updates is missing or invalid

The error occurs while deleting sharepoint list record. The sharepoint list does not have any required column.

Following is the code:

```
string batchCommand = "<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>";
batchCommand += string.Concat("<Field Name='CrfiId'>", rowId);
batchCommand += "</Field></Method></Batch>";
XmlElement batchElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("batchElement");
batchElement.InnerXml = batchCommand;

lock (_lock)
{
    xmlReturn = client.UpdateListItems(listName, batchElement);
}
```

Any idea why is this error occurring?

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in an element called "batchElement"? The method expects the root node to be the "Batch" one.

Comment: Thanks Chris for you reply :) I am using batchElement because UpdateListItems method need batchElement as second argument.do you know any other way to delete row then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ID instead of CrfiID.. You need to filter by the built-in id field, it won't work with user created fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your XML as follows;

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="Delete">
        <Field Name="ID">itemId</Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Where, for example;

```
string itemId = 5;
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I am deleting a list item not a document in document library.